# Generic argument to acess predefined methods

Tags: java

I've the following situation:

- Some classes in a package "operators", and all these classes implements an interface `Operator` with a methods `tweak` to be implemented;
- Some classes in a package "local_search", and all these classes receive one operator os "operators" as argument in the constructor method;
- My main class, where I instantiate a class of the package "local_search" and an operator of the package "operators".

My interface

```
package operators;

public interface Operator 
{
    public int[] tweak(int[] solution);
}
```

My main class:

```
package fsp;

public class FSP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException 
    {
        RandomSwap operator = new RandomSwap();
        HillClimb hc = new HillClimb(operator);
    }
}
```

One class of "local_search":

```
package local_search;

public class HillClimb
{
   Object operator;

   public HillClimb(Object operator) 
   {
      this.operator = Class.forName(operator.getClass().getName()).newInstance();   
   }
}
```

I don't know if my HillClimb constructor method is right, but I've no compilation or running time error.

What I need to do is, for example, in my HillClimb class:

```
public void start()
{
   int[] s = {1, 2, 3}
   operator.tweak(s);
}
```

If I implement that, with the examples that I gave, I can't call the `tweak` method. There is any way to do that?

**OBS**: the examples aren't the whole implementation. I kept only the necessary to explain my doubt.

EDIT1: When I call `operator.tweak(s)`, the compilation error returns: `The method tweak(int[]) is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: Since you know that `HillClimb` constructor will only take `Operator` class as argument you can simply the constructor to take `HillClimb(Operator operator)` instead of `HillClimb(Object operator)`. This way you don't even need to do `Class.forName(...)` and worry about ` ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException`. This gives you the guarantee that the object is of type `Operator` and there always will be a `tweak` method there. With the current code I can even `new HillClimb(new String())` and later it will fail while calling `start` method.

Comment: When you say you "can't call the `tweak` method", what's preventing you from doing so?  Is it a compiler error?  Is there an exception?  Can you update your question to include the feedback?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I don't have a class named `Operator`, only an interface.

Comment: You're also instantiating a new operator from an existing instance; is that your goal?

Comment: @RodrigoE. That is true and shouldn't be a problem. Constructor and method arguments can take interface as parameter. That is whole purpose of inheritance, Super class/Interface can refer to its subclass instances. As an example you might have used `List myList = new ArrayList()` where in `List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is its implementation.

Comment: @RodrigoE. In `HillClimb` class, replace `Object operator` with `Operator operator`  `HillClimb(Object operator){...}` with `HillClimb(Operator operator) {this.operator=operator;}`  and it should work without exceptions.

Comment: @adamdc78 I added the error message in EDIT1. And about your question, yes.

Comment: did you forget to implement the interface?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu it realy worked. Thanks for the answer and explanations! Use an interface as argument is a new information to me.

Comment: @sameerasy I don't need. I only implement the interface in my operator classes, like the `RandomSwap` that I used in my main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want `HillClimb` constructor to take only `Operator` class as argument you can update its constructor to take `Operator` interface as parameter.

Update

> Object operator;
>
> public HillClimb(Object operator) {..}

to

> Operator operator;
>
> public HillClimb(Operator operator)
> {
> this.operator = operator;
> }

This way you don't even need to do `Class.forName(...)` and worry about  ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException.`

Also this gives you the guarantee that the object is of type `Operator` and there always will be a tweak method there.

With the current code I can even `new HillClimb(new String())` and later it will fail while calling `start` method.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Object` to `Operator` in your class, and all your problems will go away:

```
public class HillClimb
{
    Operator operator;                  // <-- Change here

    public HillClimb(Operator operator) // <-- Change here
    {
        this.operator = operator;       // <-- Simplify this
    }
    public void start()
    {
        int[] s = {1, 2, 3}
        operator.tweak(s);
    }
}
```